# Replace in the first instance?

Tags: replace

I am trying to insert a div that'll call an ad between two paragraphs of copy text.

However, I'd like to do it only one instance. The current replace code I'm using is this - which is inserting my test code multiple times.

```
    {% set str = block.bodyText %}
    {{ str | replace('</p>
    <p>', '</p><div id="test"></div><p>') | smartypants }}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do this with Twig's `replace` filter but it is possible to do it by splitting the text into an array and iterating over it like so:

```
{% set content %}
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus.</p>
  <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
  <p>Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. </p>
{% endset %}

{% set inserted %}
  <p>Inserted text</p>
{% endset %}

{# Split text into array on closing </p> tags #}
{% for paragraph in content | split('</p>') %}
  {# Add the closing tag back, except for possible empty lines  #}
  {% set paragraph = paragraph | trim | length ? paragraph ~ '</p>' : '' %}
  {# Render the text as raw html #}
  {{ paragraph | raw }}
  {# Render the inserted paragraph on the first loop #}
  {% if loop.index == 1 %}
    {{ inserted }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: Per your question in the comment about the context, this is a good use case for a macro. This code is untested, but you might try something like this.

```
{% macro insertAfterFirstParagraph(content, insertContent) %}
  {% for paragraph in content | split('</p>') %}
    {% set paragraph = paragraph | trim | length ? paragraph ~ '</p>' : '' %}
    {{ paragraph | raw }}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
      {{ insertContent }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import insertAfterFirstParagraph %}

{% set addThisHtml %}
  <p>Add this paragraph</p>
{% endset %}

{% set isAdded = false %}
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
  {% if block.type == 'body' and loop.index > 5 and isAdded == false %}
    {{ insertAfterFirstParagraph(block.bodyField, addThisHtml) }}
    {% set isAdded = true %}
  {% else %}
    {{ block.bodyField }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Robin's suggestion to build a custom Twig filter in a plugin (or module) would be the cleanest solution, but the Twig code above should get the job done.

Aside: [Craft overrides the default Twig replace filter](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/web/twig/Extension.php#L431) to use PHP's [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) function but that filter doesn't accept the last two optional arguments, `limit` and `count`. If it did, then something like this could have worked:

```
replace('/<\\/p>\\s+?<p>/', '</p><div id="test"></div><p>', 1)
```

Maybe a feature request is in order.

Comment: This is excellent in that it has reduced the replacement to once per block, but I obviously should've included more of the code! 

        {% if block.type == "body" %}
              {% if loop.index > 5 %} 

Is before the code above - so it's running now for every body block after a certain point. Are there any ways to find the first body block after a certain number of blocks?

Comment: I updated the answer, but I have a hunch you need to count how many 'body' blocks the loop encountered. That can be done with a variable you increment every time it hits one.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to create a Twig filter that does what is explained here [replace only first appearance of string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252710/5604055)

```
{{ str|replace_once() }}
```